# When calling the REST API it does not work

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller for the time being

```js
.controller('HotelsController', ['$http', HotelsController]);

function HotelsController($http) {
  var vm = this;
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/hotels'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

but I get an error message

> CAN'T GET /api/hotels

and this is my api

```
module.exports.hotelsGetAll = function (req, res) {
        Hotel
            .find()
            .skip(offset)
            .limit(count)
            .exec(function (err, hotels) {
                if (err) {
                    res
                        .status(500)
                        .json(err);
                } else {
                    console.log("Found Hotels ", hotels.length);
                    res
                        .json(hotels);
                }

            })
    };
```

any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You should append your api host url before performing http request.

Edit your controller:

```
.controller('HotelsController', ['$http', HotelsController]);
function HotelsController($http) {
  var vm = this;
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://yourhostapiurl/api/hotels' //Append the url of your api
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me!
In addition I added these lines of codes in my server(app.js) file

```
app.all("/api/*", function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST");
    return next();
});
```